# Raster Error when Creating Heatmaps

Tags: qgis, raster, heat-map

I'm experiencing an error when trying to run a heatmap in QGIS. I just downloaded QGIS 2.18.10 'Las Palmas' on my Windows 10 Laptop as the 64 bit option.

I am hoping to run some very simple heatmaps, following the instructions laid out here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html.

I was able to follow those steps without issues when I used this in the past, but this time I get stuck after step 10 (converting the delimited text layer which I had imported from a CSV file to create the raster layer). When I follow the steps to add this layer, I receive the error "**Raster update error: Could not open the created raster for updating. The heatmap was not generated**."

My heatmap plugin came already installed, and I don't have the option to uninstall/reinstall it. Also I have already attempted to restart the program as the previous user had done.

Does anyone have suggestions as to what may have gone wrong, or what I should do differently?

Alternate instructions for creating a heatmap (to later layer over a world map and/or street view)?

Comment: Can you add more information, like screenshot of your CSV import and heatmap plugin configuration. Tested this tutorial CSV on QGIS 2.18.10 (Mint 64bit) and it works well.

Comment: Problem solved! Turns out I hadn't specified the file location (I gave it a name but not a destination in a folder).

Dumb mistake and simple fix :)

Comment: @xtiano Great! :) You can add the solution as an answer and accept it to mark this problem as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer to my own question - turns out I made the simple error of not specifying a file destination for the raster. I gave it a file name, but not a location, and that seems to be the cause of the error!

Comment: I also turn the file name into the complete location, then it works! Thanks!